# Minimum of $a^2\cot (9^\circ)+b^2\cot (27^\circ)+c^2\cot(63^\circ)+d^2\cot(81^\circ)$

Tags: inequality

> Finding minimum value of $a^2\cot (9^\circ)+b^2\cot (27^\circ)+c^2\cot(63^\circ)+d^2\cot(81^\circ)$ subjected to the condition $a+b+c+d=5,a,b,c,d$  all are real number

Try: Cauchy Schwarz Inequality

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\bigg(\cot^2(9^\circ)+\cot^2(27^\circ)+\cot^2(63^\circ)+\cot^2(81^\circ)\bigg)\geq \bigg(a\cot (9^\circ)+b\cot (27^\circ)+c\cot(63^\circ)+d\cot(81^\circ)\bigg)^2$$

Could some help me how to solve, thanks

Comment: Are you supposed to knwo about Lagrange multipliers ? If not, when you will learn about them, you will be amazed to see how they make this problem simple.

Comment: To claude Leibovici how i  solve using multiplier method.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint

$$(a^2\cot \,9°+b^2\cot \,27°+c^2\cot \,63°+d^2\cot \,81°)(\tan \,9^\circ+\tan \,27^\circ+\tan \,63^\circ+\tan \,81^\circ)\ge \left (\sum a\right)^2= 25 $$

Answer (score 2):

$$[a^2\cot 9^\circ+b^2\cot 27^\circ+c^2\cot63^\circ+d^2\cot81^\circ][\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ]\ge(a+b+c+d)^2$$